# Type of Noun- Knowledge

Tags: nouns

i have a sentence

> His knowledge of many languages elevated him among his companions.

Which type of noun is knowledge.

> Collective noun
>
> Material noun
>
> Abstract noun
>
> Concrete noun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an abstract noun.

Abstract nouns are words that name things that are not concrete.

Your five physical senses cannot detect an abstract noun – you can’t see it, smell it, taste it, hear it, or touch it.

In essence, an abstract noun is a quality, a concept, an idea, or maybe even an event.

Read more about abstract nouns [here](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/abstract-nouns/).